# SQL Server update with random values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a table generating random "pin" numbers. This is what I'm trying but in the end all the rows are getting the same number. I have tried doing it in a while cycle but it is still the same.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

---- This will create a random number between 10000 and 99999
SET @Lower = 10000 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 99999 ---- The highest random number

UPDATE Totals 
SET Pin =  ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)

--check for repeated numbers
SELECT
    Pin, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Totals
GROUP BY
    Pin
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1

    --commit
    --rollback
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` instead of `RAND()` to get around `RAND()` being evaluated once:

```
UPDATE totals
SET pin = (@Lower + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % (@Upper-@Lower+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` is evaluated once per query.

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + @Lower), 0) as new_Pin
      FROM Totals
     )
UPDATE Totals 
    SET Pin = new_Pin;
```

One way around this is to use `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`.  However, you still have to be careful about expressions and subqueries being optimized to run only once.  I think the above formulation should work.